# Editing photo dimensions in large batches

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

If I had the time, I would go through each and every photo to make sure that the dimensions and quality are pixel perfect. However, I'm in a time crunch, and need to make the couple hundred photos that are 4320 x 3240 into 950x630.

now I could-
1. Upload them into WordPress, uses native image reducing components and J query go from there.
2. Go through each and every photo, reduce file size, and proportion and bring it to Yahoo's PNG processing script.

However, maybe I'm missing a choice or alternative workflow that would allow for processing all of these photos in a clear manner without losing quality or perspectives. Any workflow suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a *Photoshop Batch* to re-size the images.

This is how you do it:

**Step 1: Create an action for the re-sizing**

Actions are a great way of saving time when you need to do repetitive tasks in Photoshop. You can record a process, and then 'play' it to repeat it, and you can add as many steps in that process as you like.

In your case, the first thing you need to do is record an action that resizes an image to 950x630 px. You can do this by using the Actions panel (Windows > Actions, or Ctrl + F9):

1. Go to `Window > Actions` to bring up the Actions palette.
2. Click `Create new action` and give it a name like "Resize"
3. Click `Record`.
4. In the main Photoshop menu bar, go to `Image > Image Size`.
5. Select "Pixels" from the drop-down menu next to Width.
6. Type in "950" and click `OK`.
7. Go to the Actions palette and click on the `Stop` button to stop recording.

You should see your new action in your palette.

**Step 2: Apply the action to a folder of images using a Batch**

Once you have recorded the action, you can tell Photoshop to (instead of just applying it inside the same file) use it in a folder.

1. Go to `File > Automate > Batch` to bring up the Batch dialog.
2. Find the "Resize" action you just recorded in the Actions drop-down list.
3. Under the Source header, select "Folder" in the drop-down list and click Choose. Navigate to the folder where you keep your images.
4. Check the boxes to suppress warnings and options dialogs.
5. Under the Destination header, select "Folder" in the drop-down list and click `Choose`. Navigate to the folder.
6. If you want to change the names of your files, you can do so here under the `File Naming` sub-header.
7. Make sure you have the "Compatibility" boxes checked.
8. Click `OK`.

Comment: This worked out great. Thank you so much for the workflow and rundown. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked! Remember to tick the preferred answer to your questions, I see you have a few ones in which you haven't chosen one (did you not find what you were looking for? You can always edit them and they will be bumped to the top to probably get more answers)

Answer (score 4):

It would appear you are looking for the image processor within Photoshop.

To find it go to `File > Scripts > Image Processor`

[image]

Select the desired folder

[image]

Input the destination.  If you dont do this step I believe it just saves it over the files.  Its been awhile since I have used it.

[image]

add your settings

[image]

Here is a [video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/understanding-adobe-photoshop-cs6/image-processor-script/) on it that uses CS6.

Answer (score 0):

### [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

Whenever it comes to batch processing of a large number of files we may want to consider using the immensely versatile image processor tools provided by the Image Magick. This software is cross-platform (Unix, Windows, Mac OS X, iOS), Open Source, and provides many parameters to fine-tune the results for professional usage.

To resize an image we may use the convert tool with the parameter [resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) from a command line (best from the folder our images live in). ImageMagick supports wildcards `*` and `?` for batch conversion:

```
convert *.png -resize <geometry> resized.png
```

Give in the desired [geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) values. For a width of 950 pixels this would be just the number `950`.

But this is not all we can do. We can also adjust the color space from sRGB to RGB before we scale the image for much better color results:

```
convert *.png -colorspace RGB -resize 950 -colorspace sRGB resized.png
```

We may also use an spline filter with additional sharpening of the resized image to reduce blurring with the spline and the [unsharp](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize_unsharp) filter (experiment with different values for best result):

```
convert *.png -colorspace RGB -filter spline -resize 950  -unsharp 0x1 -colorspace sRGB resized.png
```

For an overview of resizing techniques using Image Magick I recommend this nice tutorial:

- [Image Magick Resizing Techniques](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#techniques)

Comment: I *suspect* without doing any testing myself, that IM is probably faster than PS when batch processing.

Comment: This may well be, but as soon as we add filters it will slow down considerably.

Comment: this may be a great solution for another process. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

imagemagick is a command-line tool that is perfectly suited to batch processing. It will probably best suit you if you are just a little bit familiar with Linux/Unix shell.

The resize command is described [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize). It has a whole lot of other functionality too.